# Use yootheme layouts on an already running joomla site

Tags: templates, css, template-override, layout, style

I'm using yootheme's solar on my website and I want to change it for the stage theme, I want to make my site to look just like this:

http://yootheme.com/demo/joomla/stage

but it's impossible since the demo package can only be installed on a brand new joomla site and mine has a lot of information which make it impossible.

I'm running out of ideas, I've tried to replace some layouts files in the installation package [and then creating a .zip], or copying the CSS styles to my custom CSS but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no simple way to get your Joomla site look exactly like the demo. Template demos are just that: a demonstration of how the template *can* look, and a showcase of all the available visual effects. Custom content, modules, code and CSS is often included in the live template demo, but not in the template download.

That being said, it's usually a lot easier to change to another template from the same template provider, because the module positions are the same, as well as most of the CSS framework.

Here are some advice and ideas:

1. Make sure you work on a copy of your website, not the live site (obviously).
2. Based on how much custom content you have, decide whether you prefer to start with the demo package and copy your content to the new site, or modify your existing site with the new content. In your case the latter sounds like a better choice.
3. Install the template on your site, and set it as default. Your site will probably look weird at first, but don't worry about it yet. Use your original live site to see how it was before.
4. Install the demo package to a separate folder. You can use this as a reference to see how a particular part of the demo is set up. Then replicate this on your own site.
5. Read the online documentation. I'm not familiar with YooTheme, but most template providers include detailed instructions (and code examples) to show you how to replicate the demo.
6. Don't aim at having your website look *exactly* like the demo. Adjust the *layout to fit your site and content*, not the other way around.
7. Place your modules in the right positions first (maybe you don't need to move them at all, if module positions are the same). Then make adjustments in your *custom.css* file if needed.
8. Remember that [Module suffixes](https://docs.joomla.org/Module_Class_Suffix) often are required in order to replicate the demo.
9. Ask the support team if you're stuck on how to replicate a certain part of the site. They should know their template in and out, and help you.

Hope this helps a little. But keep in mind that changing template is a time consuming process, especially if your site is content heavy.

Comment: thank you so much for your ideas, I'm going to give a try and see how much of the demo theme I can replicate on my own site. BTW, what do you mean by installing the theme in a separate folder? Just uncompressing it to copy the desired files to my site, or you mean something else?

Comment: The [demo package](http://yootheme.com/themes/documentation/getting-started/setup-a-theme-demo-package) is a replica of the template demo, including both Joomla, the tempate and all settings from the demo. Great for use as reference. Extract the contents to on a web server (or localhost) like you normally would do with Joomla, visit the folder in your browser and follow instructions. Use a different database than your original site has.